# product images with no loss of quality (or pixel perfect, with no processing/resizing done at all)?

Tags: image, magento

I have spent a lot of time on my product images, adjusting them to perfectly match the actual product's color..  white balance, tint, contrast, hue..  But now when I look at them in Magento, they have been butchered beyond belief.  For my products, it is mandatory that the images appear precisely as do the products.  I have plenty of bandwidth and am not concerned with minimizing file size.  I also do not mind if I have to manually resize and upload the same image two or three times if I can somehow bypass the processing that is happening altogether.

Magento is great!  But this is a showstopper.  I cannot launch the website if the images do not look right.  If I can't do this, I'm actually going to have to ditch this cart which I've spent months learning, or spend a lot of time coming up with my own solution even though I have no low-level mysql experience.  Either way, delaying launch would really hurt financially.

I have attempted to insert ->setQuality(99), after the call to init() and before the call to resize(), in \catalog\product\view\media.phtml, and also after the call to init() in \catalog\product\gallery.phtml.

in both cases I have also used setQuality(10) to ensure that I have done it properly, and strangely it works in gallery.phtml but not in media.phtml.  It doesn't matter though, because even though the 100 value in gallery.phtml is not too bad in terms of detail, unfortunately contrast/color/exposure is different.  It looks washed out and desaturated.  It makes the product look unappealing.

In a thread at magentocommerce.com, someone suggested that it is the resize() function that is causing the problem, but that can't be true because resize() is not called within gallery.phtml.  In general people have pointed to GD2.php as the culprit, but I haven't found any solutions that get around it completely.

If I were to upload a 265 px width image for the media.phtml view, and a separate one of the same photo using whatever resolution I desire for the blown-up gallery.phtml view, how would I tag those in the backend (base or small? or will I need more tags?) and then how would I access the proper image from the phtml files?  This is a bit over my head.  I think I can figure it out but not without spending a lot of time, which I do not have.  Is there an extension that exists that already has tackled this problem?  I notice that some of the "lightbox" extensions are popular, but none of their descriptions mention anything about overcoming the horrendous image quality spit out by gd2, which makes me doubt that they do.

Can someone please offer some advice?  If there is already an extension, I would be so pleased.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the best solution is to switch from Magento's default Gd2 library to [ImageMagick](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php) for more control and better resolution. The Magento forums have a post with the details [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewreply/299873/). You need to make sure that your edits are performed in an upgrade-safe manner.

Comment: thanks for the reply.  OK I have tried reddog's thread's solution, and it is not making any difference.  I downloaded and installed Image Magick for Windows, making sure to leave the "add to path" checkbox checked as instructed, and I copied the dll to the php extension folder.  Then I copied GD2.php to /app/code/local/Varien/Image/Adapter/, commented out the call to "call_user_func_array" in save(), and inserted the specificed lines afterwards.  My caching has been disabled, so no problem there I would think.  I had restarted WAMP, and it does show that php_imagick_ts is loaded.

Comment: btw I deleted the cache files for the heck of it.  Still no difference.

Comment: oh, actually turns out you have to reupload your images because the save() function that is modified doesn't get called until then.  Well, I did that, and now I'm getting a php error "class IMagick not found".  Huh.

Comment: Jonathan, the next user down "cheeseandrice" posted a GD2.php file that worked after I uploaded the images again!  I'll answer my question here in a while with that solution

Comment: good to hear. I would still recommend that you try with ImageMagick again if you can get the paths correct on Windows. You will get better results overall with ImageMagick than Gd2, even at 100%

Comment: OK I may still do that once things settle down.  I also want to take a closer look at the modified gd2.php that I am using now to see exactly what it is doing.  Supposedly it is avoiding GD2 altogether, which is fine by me, since I've already optimized my images, but I could see a point where I would still want to be able to easily resize images.  I'm not sure yet, but I feel that it's probably still allowing for some resizing somehow, but I haven't finished my css yet to fully understand which images are being used and where.  I will update this as I learn more.  It's strange that this is the

Comment: ..state of things, since Magento is so widely used by professionals.  It can't be that they all have accepted the default image quality, which at least one respected Magento community member has admitted "is a disaster".  Either they do accept it, or they have available to them a better solution through the Enterprise suite.  If the latter, it just makes me wonder why this isn't available to Community Edition by default.  CE is evolving, but this is the sort of thing that I would have thought would have been solved and integrated years ago.  I'm still miffed about losing my entire Saturday :)

Comment: there's not any difference in Enterprise AFAIK. I suspect it's on their (very long) list of things to work on. With over 2 million lines of code in the current release (for free!), its probably understandable...